# tables of reductions in literature

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

I'm interested in tables of which problems are reducible to which other problems. Particularly for graph problems, but any such tables/graphs would be neat, just so I know how to look for them. Professors in lectures used to draw them on the blackboard, but I can't seem to find them in literature.

Comment: Technically, all $\mathsf{NP}$-complete problems have (polynomial time) reductions between each other. If we introduce some sort of natural reduction graph, one could start at [Karp's 21 problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%27s_21_NP-complete_problems).

Comment: *Thousands* of problems have been considered in the literature, hence this is too broad a request to be answerable. Also, *tables* seem an odd and counterintuitive way of conveying this information. I’m not even sure what such a table would look like; you mean an adjacency matrix of the reducibility relation with +/- entries, or something else? Usually, reducibilities among multiple problems are depicted using a Hasse diagram instead, such as in https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~greg/zoology/diagram.xml (though this particular diagram is for complexity classes rather than individual problems).

Comment: Also look in, e.g., CLRS intro algorithm's text, or Sipser's theory of computation text.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this classic textbook useful: Computers and Intractability: A Guide to the Theory of NP-Completeness, by Michael Garey and David S. Johnson.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computers_and_Intractability